# Display python variable in tensorboard

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

i wanna display some python variables in tensorboard, but i dont get it done.

My code so far, display only a line in tensorboard for the lines with static number, if i use the outcommented-lines, it does not work ? It then prints:
ValueError: Shapes () and (?,) are not compatible

Someone has an idea?

```
import tensorflow as tf

step = 0
session = tf.Session()

tensorboardVar = tf.Variable(0, "tensorboardVar")

pythonVar = tf.placeholder("int32", [None])

#update_tensorboardVar = tensorboardVar.assign(pythonVar)
update_tensorboardVar = tensorboardVar.assign(4)
tf.scalar_summary("myVar", update_tensorboardVar)

merged = tf.merge_all_summaries()

sum_writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter('/tmp/train/c/', session.graph)

session.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())


for i in range(100):
        _, result = session.run([update_tensorboardVar, merged])
        #_, result = session.run([update_tensorboardVar, merged], feed_dict={pythonVar: i})
        sum_writer.add_summary(result, step)
        step += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

this is working:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

step = 0
session = tf.Session()

tensorboardVar = tf.Variable(0, "tensorboardVar")

pythonVar = tf.placeholder("int32", [])

update_tensorboardVar = tensorboardVar.assign(pythonVar)
tf.scalar_summary("myVar", update_tensorboardVar)

merged = tf.merge_all_summaries()

sum_writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter('/tmp/train/c/', session.graph)

session.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())


for i in range(100):
        #_, result = session.run([update_tensorboardVar, merged])
        j = np.array(i)
        _, result = session.run([update_tensorboardVar, merged], feed_dict={pythonVar: j})
        sum_writer.add_summary(result, step)
        step += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way can be found in the second answer to [Computing exact moving average over multiple batches in tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35714995/computing-exact-moving-average-over-multiple-batches-in-tensorflow). There it is shown how you can create custom summaries.